# Reducing voltage with resisitors

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, electronics

I am working on a project in structure, in which i have to rotate the second storey of my building, now my assembly consists of 12 v battery connected in parallel with  12v motor which is connected to a shaft,which in turn is connected to blades/paddle wheel , and those blades are joined with the floor of 2nd storey using screws, my problem is that the wheel rotates at high speed, i have to limit the speed, but i couldn't find a voltage regulator, so how can i reduce the voltage given to the motor using resitors. I am not good at circuits, so please make it as simple as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general reducing the voltage to control the rpm of a motor is not a good strategy and it's even worse when executed with resistors.

If you use a resistor, the voltage drop on the resistor will be $V_{R}=RI_m$, i.e. the remaining voltage for the motor will be $V_m=V_0-V_R=V_{supply}-RI_m$. The more torque the motor has to generate, the higher the current $I_m$ will be and the more voltage will drop across the resistor and the less will be available for the motor. Since the output power of the motor is $P=V_{m}I_m=(V_{supply}-RI_m)I_m=V_0I_m - RI_m^2$, there will be a roughly quadratically increasing power loss with increasing torque. Since the motor will need a substantial current just to start moving, the resistor method usually leads to very poor start behavior.

If you don't have a voltage regulator, at the very least try your luck with several diodes in series. Each diode will drop the voltage by approx. 0.7V, relatively independent of the motor current $I_m$. This only imposes a motor power penalty that is roughly linear with $I_m$. The diodes to need to be able to handle the motor current and a power dissipation of $I_m\times0.7V$.

In practice even this is not a very good solution. I would always use a motor controller for this purpose, if possible. They are cheap and they get the job really done.